# How to write data to a file using javascript?I

Tags: javascript, file, security

I know by default this is not allowed , can you help me how to change the security settings so that i can write to a file.
thank you

Comment: You can't.  Try https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify

Comment: From the web? You can even by overriding some defaults.

Comment: Do you want to write a file to the actual drive, or just the html5 filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

there is absolutely no way to write to a file with a browser.
but modern browsers like Chrome allow you to create files on the fly

In this example i add a textarea to the document.

this has a eventlistener onchange.(so write something and blur it clicking outside)

onchange it reads the value of your textarea and converts it into base64

which is easely done with `btoa()`

the data is added to the href of a new created anchor which is prefixed with (text/plain) as mimetype and data: telling the browser that it's a DATA STRING and not a link.

Chrome also has a new attribute called `download` on anchors. which is basically the filename.

this is the fastest and easiest way in modern browsers to create a file clientside..

you just have to click to download it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>write to file</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var t=document.createElement('textarea');
t.addEventListener('change',function(){
 var a=document.createElement('a');
 a.download='text.txt';
 a.innerText='download';
 a.href='data:text/plain;base64,'+btoa(this.value);
 document.body.appendChild(a);
},false)
document.body.appendChild(t);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

another solution is to use the also modern browser only `window.filesystem` which stores the files you want in a virtual chrome cache(temporany or persistant).
Filesystem can store big files as blobs and it uses low resources.

then there is localstorage/indexedDB/websql for tiny files.

in the last solution you need to save your data as base64 else you can'tstore your info.

in all of the solutions you have the files in your browser,you need a modern browser....but you need to download the file.

if you want to write data on a already existing file you can use `FileReadr()` with `FileWriter.append()` and drag & drop or just a simple file input to select the existing file.